# Alternative to RemoveAt and Insert list items

Tags: c#, list

I am looking for a better data structure or method to simply replace an object in an dynamic array. It seems like list is the choice, however I read and notice that the performance of RemoveAt and Insert is not as good as I had hoped.

Let me elaborate on what I am trying to achieve:

> List1
>
> 1. List item 1
> 2. List item 2
> 3. List item 3
>
> List2
>
> 1. List item 1
> 2. List item 2
> 3. Null

Both list uses the same object types. I want to replace the null list item of List2 with List1[1] -- List item 1 clone. I use a clone so the value of the copied list item is a separate instance.

I also want to replace list item 2 of List2 with a clone of list item 1 of List2.

Here is some example code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
projCraneVertices.RemoveAt(projCraneVertices.Count - 4);
projCraneVertices.Insert((projCraneVertices.Count - 3), realCraneVertices[botPoint].clone());
projCraneVertices.RemoveAt(projCraneVertices.Count - 3);
projCraneVertices.Insert((projCraneVertices.Count - 2), projCraneVertices[botPoint].clone());
projCraneVertices.RemoveAt(projCraneVertices.Count - 2);
projCraneVertices.Insert((projCraneVertices.Count - 1), realCraneVertices[topPoint].clone());
projCraneVertices.RemoveAt(projCraneVertices.Count - 1);
projCraneVertices.Insert((projCraneVertices.Count), projCraneVertices[topPoint].clone());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want to replace list item 2 of List2 with a clone of list item
>   1 of List2.

Well, you can do it simpler like this:

```
proCraneVertices[2] =  realCraneVertices[1].Clone();
```

Comment: I thought it should be this easy. I tried something similar to this before without the clone function and it was not working as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you want a `Replace` method. Try this extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static void Replace<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, T item)
  {
    list[index] = item;
  }
}
```

Call like:

```
  List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
  List<int> ints2 = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 };
  ints.Replace(0, ints2[0]);
```

The above will make the first list - `4, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 0):

using List of T will solve you problem of removeAt and inset this uses Array under the hood and will expose some good functions to you that will help to ridoff these anoing methods.

you can use some of function provided by List like below.

Replace // Replact the item from one item to another item

[List of T Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)